# How to use same column in columns and values in Apache poi pivot

Tags: java, pivot, apache-poi

I am trying to create pivot using Apache poi, everything is working fine expect one scenario. When I am trying to use same column in columns and values(aggregator) it is not working.

[image]

For example this is my sheet and I want to add "icecream" column in both columns and values then it's not working.

Adding column below is pivot code:

```
 addColumnLabel(pivotTable, dataSheet, areaReference, 0, true);

addColumnLabel(XSSFPivotTable pivotTable, Sheet dataSheet, AreaReference areaReference,
                            int column, boolean isColumn) {
        try {
            DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter(java.util.Locale.US);
            
            java.util.TreeSet<String> uniqueItems = new java.util.TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
            for (int r = areaReference.getFirstCell().getRow() + 1; r < areaReference.getLastCell().getRow()
                    + 1; r++) {
                uniqueItems.add(formatter.formatCellValue(dataSheet.getRow(r).getCell(column)));
            }
           
            if (isColumn) {
                //pivotTable.addColLabel(column);
                int lastColIndex = areaReference.getLastCell().getCol() - areaReference.getFirstCell().getCol();

                CTPivotFields pivotFields = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields();

                CTPivotField pivotField = CTPivotField.Factory.newInstance();
                CTItems items = pivotField.addNewItems();

                pivotField.setAxis(STAxis.AXIS_COL);
                pivotField.setShowAll(false);
                for (int i = 0; i <= lastColIndex; i++) {
                    items.addNewItem().setT(STItemType.DEFAULT);
                }
                items.setCount(items.sizeOfItemArray());
                pivotFields.setPivotFieldArray(column, pivotField);

                // colfield should be added for the second one.
                CTColFields colFields;
                if (pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getColFields() != null) {
                    colFields = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getColFields();
                } else {
                    colFields = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().addNewColFields();
                }
                colFields.addNewField().setX(column);
                colFields.setCount(colFields.sizeOfFieldArray());
            } 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And for adding aggregator using below line:

```
pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.COUNT, 0, "Count of icecream");
```

Excel is getting exported but it is showing repair and getting closed automatically.

Output should be something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache POI does not support a pivot field to be a axis field (row label and/or column label)  and a data field (subtotal field) the same time.

`XSSFPivotTable.addRowLabel` sets the pivot field to have axis settings and items but it removes a data field attribute if present.

`XSSFPivotTable.addColumnLabel` sets the pivot field to be a data field having data field attribute but removes axis settings and items if present. Additional it adds a data field having given subtotal and name for it.

So if you first do `addRowLabel` and then `addColumnLabel` for the same field, then you get a correct data field but a pivot field without axis settings and items. That fails.

If you first do `addColumnLabel` and then `addRowLabel` for the same field, then you get a correct data field and a pivot field having axis settings and items but not having a data field attribute. That fails too.

Shortest workaround is to first do `addColumnLabel` and then `addRowLabel` for the same field and then add the removed data field attribute again.

Complete example, your efforts to create correct pivot items left aside:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

class CreatePivotTable {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("./Excel.xlsx") ) {

   Sheet pivotSheet = workbook.createSheet("Pivot");
   Sheet dataSheet = workbook.createSheet("Data");

   Row row;
   Cell cell;
   Object[][] data = new Object[][]{
    new Object[]{"icecream", "company"},
    new Object[]{"blueberry", "abc"},
    new Object[]{"mango", "xyz"},
    new Object[]{"vanilla", "pqr"},
    new Object[]{"blueberry", "abc"},
    new Object[]{"mango", "xyz"},
    new Object[]{"blueberry", "abc"},
    new Object[]{"vanilla", "pqr"},
    new Object[]{"blueberry", "abc"},
    new Object[]{"vanilla", "pqr"}
   };
   for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
    row = dataSheet.createRow(r);
    Object[] rowData = data[r];
    for (int c = 0; c < rowData.length; c++) {
     cell = row.createCell(c);
     if (rowData[c] instanceof String) {
      cell.setCellValue((String)rowData[c]);
     }
    }
   }

   AreaReference areaReference = new AreaReference(
    new CellReference(0,0),
    new CellReference(data.length-1, data[0].length-1),
    SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);

   XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = ((XSSFSheet)pivotSheet).createPivotTable(areaReference, new CellReference("A4"), dataSheet);

   // following sets pivot field 0 to be a data field having data field attribute but removes axis settings and items if present
   // then it adds a data field having given subtotal and name for it
   pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.COUNT, 0, "Count of icecream");
   
   // following sets pivot field 0 to have axis settings and items
   // but it removes data field attribute if present
   pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);
   
   // following re-adds data field attribute
   pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(0).setDataField(true);

   workbook.write(fileout);

  }

 }
}
```

Comment: Great Thanks that worked for rows but if add in columns excel gives error. could help how to add icecream in columns instead of rows?

Comment: @user3458271: My example creates what you have shown in your question. And if I do `pivotTable.addColLabel(0);` instead of `pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);` in my example, it results in icecream being the column label.